# What are the different ways to store develop and distribution certificates to your Mac, Keychain and Xcode?

Tags: xcode, certificate, code-signing, keychain, provisioning-profile

Is it correct to say that you can download a certificate through either of the following ways:

- Create the certificate on Apple Developer Portal and download it and store it into keychain
- Create Provisioning profiles on Apple Developer Portal and download the Provisioning profile. The certificate will come along with that and will get stored into your keychain.
- Use 'Automatically manage signing'. It will create the certificate for either development or distribution depending on your build settings and store into your keychain. Will also add the device you're building into the provisioning profile.

My questions:

1. Is what I mentioned correct?
2. Is there any other way of adding certificates to your Mac?
3. Also is there any difference between development and distribution certificates in terms of how you can add them to your Mac/Keychain/Xcode? From what I've understood, it's not different. It's just that you may not have access to distribution certs

Comment: "Also is there any difference between develop and distribution certificates in terms of how you can add them to your Mac?" Well, obviously yes, in the sense that the times when you need them are different, and also because of the clear numerical difference.

Comment: My question is focused on the manner you can retrieve them and have them into your keychain. The difference I'm aware of is that you can't distribute to App store with develop certificate. I don't know what you mean by numerical difference. Do you mean the actual value of the certificate is different?